# How can I find the doc_count of items in open search index per x day per 3 hours

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Using opensearch I need to write an aggregation that gets me the doc_count of items in the index every 3 hours per 2 days. So I would get the response from opensearch of the number of documents every 3 hours with an interval of every 2 days

I tried writing an aggregation with 2d as interval and then a sub aggregation of 3h as interval. But gave me each time appearing twice with doc_count value.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "2d",
        "min_doc_count": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "three_hour": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "@timestamp",
            "interval": "3h",
            "format": "HH:mm",
            "min_doc_count": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if that is the only approach to do it or is there another way

Comment: It's not clear what response you get vs what response you expect, maybe add some examples.